# Compare two files to find the same output in each

Tags: files

I have a `file1.txt` and `file2.txt` i want to tell if all the information in `file1` is in `file2`. If it is, then output it to `file3.txt` otherwise dont do anything.

I looked at `comm` command and diff, but it isnt apparent `comm` may be best for this use case.

can someone help?

Thanks

Answer (score 0):

I resolved my own issue with the following, maybe it will help someone:

```
$ comm -1 -2 <file1.txt> <file2.txt>
```